# Method invocation failed because [System.RuntimeType] for GetCurrentThreadId

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to get windows process's memory dump with below powershell script.

I used to try this script. But it's give following error:

> Method invocation failed because [System.RuntimeType] does not contain
> a method named 'GetCurrentThreadId'.

```
#############################################################
$process = Get-Process -Name AggregatorHost
$threadId = [System.Diagnostics.Process].GetCurrentThreadId()
$thread = $process.Threads | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq $threadId }
$thread.Export("test.dmp")
###################################################################
```

How to solve this problem or pls tell me if you have other way?

powershell memory dump

Answer (score 0):

`Process.GetCurrentTheadId` is a *static* method, so you need to use the static member invocation operator `::` (as opposed to the regular member invocation operator `.`):

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentThreadId()
```

That being said, I doubt the code you've presented is going to do what you expect - `GetCurrentThreadId` will get the thread id from the executing thread *in the powershell process*, and you're not going to find the same thread id *belonging to another process* during the same boot cycle

Answer (score 0):

`[System.RuntimeType]` does not contain a method named '`GetCurrentThreadId`'.

Let's find a type *containing* such a method:

```
Get-Type -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Where-Object {$_.GetMethods().Name -eq 'GetCurrentThreadId'} |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

> ```
> System.AppDomain
> ```

However, the following code snippet shows that thread identified in such a way (`GetCurrentThreadId` static method of the [`System.AppDomain` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain)) belongs to calling process (hence, can't be found in `Get-Process -Name AggregatorHost`):

```
$PID
Get-Process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Where-Object {
        $_.Threads.Id -eq [System.AppDomain]::GetCurrentThreadId()
    } 2>$null
```

> ```
> 11492
>
> Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
> -------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
>     559      37    70280      87944       2.31  11492   1 powershell
> ```

Moreover:

> `AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId` has been deprecated because it does not
> provide a stable Id when managed threads are running on fibers (aka
> lightweight threads). To get a stable identifier for a managed thread,
> use the `ManagedThreadId` property on `Thread` instead.